# DocuSign Signing groups Import from One account to other Account "Same Signing group ID"

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to get DocuSign Signing groups from account ABC and create same Signing GROUP in account XYZ? We know that we can create signing groups using DocuSign API. Our main concern is that We want to create/import Signing Groups with same SigningGroupID.

As we are saving Signing group ID in our application processes and we want to use same Signing group IDs in some other user account.

Could you please confirm us if this is possible and will not cause any issues?

Is there any other option available for us?

Answer (score 0):

Signing groups are an account object. That means they are part of a specific account. They use a numeric identifier (up to 1,000,000) that is unique inside the account and is generated randomly when you use the API to create a new one.
There's no way to set the group ID directly.
Your best solution is to have a mapping table in your database that maps your groups to your accounts. Another solution is to first make an API call to obtain (list) all the groups and find the one you want and its ID. That solution is less recommended as it requires an extra API call each time.

Comment: Thanks Inbar , There is one property in C# SDK SigningGroupID. I can assign value to It.

Comment: It is in the model for when you get data back, the value will be ignored when you make a POST call to create a group.